# org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: \"document\" is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google maps to get the coordinates of a location. My code is running exactly how I want it to however when I click save on the form I get the error in the above title.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
function init(){
    //Calls the loadScript and initialize function and loads the Google Maps API 
    loadScript('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?APIKEY&callback=initialize');
}

function loadScript(src,callback){
    //Adds the google maps script to the head of the HTML
    alert('loading');
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if(callback)script.onload=callback;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.src = src;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently all I needed was a try catch around the code:

```
function loadScript(src,callback){
    //Adds the google maps script to the head of the HTML
    try{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if(callback)script.onload=callback;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.src = src;
    }catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
  }
```